# osmdroid Cannot resolve method 'getInstance()'

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid version 6.0.1 for my app and I'm trying to set the HTTP User-Agent, but when I use this code:

```
Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
```

the error "Cannot resolve method 'getInstance()'" occurs.

Comment: Maybe you imported some other `Configuration` class instead of `org.osmdroid.config.Configuration`(?)

Comment: You are right. Thanks!